# Prevent Direct Access to Files and Serve via readfile() Without Execute Permission

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-permissions, readfile

I am working on a project where users can upload files to my server. I want to store the files in a folder without execute permissions and I want to force the user to access the file via a php file. I am on shared hosting.

If I call the file from root folder i.e. '/home/user/Website.com/Files/MyFile.ext' the file will need execute permissions because it executes before `readfile()` sends it to the user. If I call it from 'https://Website.com/MyFile.ext' I don't need execute permissions but the resource is either prevented by my .htaccess file or it visible to the user via the url.

My current solution is to set the folder permissions to 601 and to set my .htaccess in 'https://Website.com/Files' to

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.ServerIpAddress
```

and my php file to

```
readfile('https://Website.com/Files/MyFile.ext');
exit();
```

This does the desired behavior and I think this would be good enough if I was on my own server but since I am on shared hosting I suspect someone who shares my IP address would be able to access my files and I am looking for an alternative method.

Comment: You cannot store the files outside the webroot? That would be much simpler and less prone to errors.

Comment: @KIKI Software. If I call the resource below the root '/home/user/' it will require execute permissions because it will execute before ```readfile()``` sends it to the user. I am trying to avoid allowing execute permissions on files because I might not know whats in them.

Comment: If that is so (is it?), then I wouldn't use `readfile()`, but something more basic like `fopen("path to file", "r");` which opens for reading only. There's a write variant of that as well. Relying on .htaccess to hide files will work, but what if they're not properly configured, will you find this out in time?

Comment: @KIKO Software Thanks for questioning that. Looked into what execute permissions mean on a folder and if I read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150449/what-does-execute-permission-mean-on-a-folder correctly it prevents looking into that folder. Not sure why behavior is different when I use root directory instead of the url but I think storing the files outside the webroot will work fine.